# Default "Unsalvageable" option default to vote close when available

Tags: feature-request, triage

As an user who recently gained the reputation to vote close questions instead of flagging them, I wonder why the `Unsalvageable` decision in the triage queue does not default to vote close the item at hand instead of just flagging it, and just adding workload to the vote close queues. Of course this should be a switch for users in the triage queue, who can only flag yet.

Comment: When you can cast close-votes, your flags are directly converted to close votes. (When applicable, of course).

Comment: Oh you are right, didn"t saw that.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, you *can't* flag questions (for closure), once you've unlocked CVs (they aren't converted). When you click the "should be closed" or "duplicate" options in the flagging dialog, the close vote dialog **is** the actual dialog that opens, hence the message at the top of the dialog says *"Vote to close questions that can’t or shouldn’t be answered on Stack Overflow. Learn more about the close and reopen votes privilege."* and it shows your *votes* remaining, not your *flags* remaining. This is also why after retracting a close vote you *can't* flag for closure.

Answer (score 3):

As comments mentioned this is already implemented, the "flag" action changes to a vote when the appropriate close reason is selected

[image]

[image]